# How do you rephrase a quality about yourself as a skill, specifically, being detail oriented?

Tags: word-choice

I am filling out questions for a job application on-line. I am to list the top skills I used in my last position. The job I had was somewhat like editing, but for item records on a library circulation system. Mentioning my linguistics training doesn't exactly fit the bill. However it absolutely required a detail oriented eye. What say you?

Comment: If you pride yourself on attention to detail, you might want to check your text here - *"questions"*, *"it asked to list"*, *"skills as I used"* are all flawed. (I'll take it you realise that *"What say you?"* is a quaint archaism! :)

Comment: Are you thinking of *Meticulous?*

Comment: I am ashamed of the fact that I didn't proofread my own question before posting. But the quaint phrase stays, if only out of spite for your derisive remark.

Answer (score 3):

Having "*an eye for detail*" is a common term and is appropriate for job applications.

For example, it can be found in an [example covering letter](http://careers.guardian.co.uk/covering-letter-examples) on The Guardian newspaper's  careers advice site.

> I am a fast and accurate writer, **with a keen eye for detail** and I should be very grateful for the opportunity to progress to market reporting.

Answer (score 1):

Why not *detail-driven record editing*?

Comment: I like your phrasing and it actually helps me with another question, but this more describes the position rather than a skill.

Comment: I'm into alliteration, so how about _minutiae-minded_?

Comment: Why the downvote?  :|

Comment: Oh no, that was a slip of the wrist yesterday and I distinctly remember undoing it. There, we go.

Answer (score 0):

I think *attention to detail* might work.  It's simple and well-understood – common, but not overused.

You might also want to emphasize how important it was to keep the records accurate, and how much data was involved.  That would help set *attention to detail* into context, rather than leaving it alone and nebulous.

> *Job demanded 100% accuracy, with meticulous attention to detail for thousands of records*.